# differentiation and Leibniz notation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, notation

If I differentiate and multiply to $x$ a function and do it repeatedly, then is it right the following notation??

for example:

$x(\frac{d}{dx}x(\frac{d}{dx}x(\frac{d}{dx}x(\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))))))=(x\frac{d}{dx})^4(f(x)$

Comment: Yes, it's okay to write $(x \frac{d}{dx})^4 f(x).$

Comment: @md2perpe thanks a lot